# <Swift>How to navigate to a new page in custom cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom cell FeedCell.swift and the controller FeedViewController.swift. And I set a btn in each cell so that I can navigate to detailController.swift. But in custom cell I can't use self.navigation. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set an outlet of Button in cell and addTarget it like :

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID") as! yourCell
        cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goDetail), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func goDetail(){
        let vc = // Declare your viewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
    }
```

Btw you can add this action when a cell selected instead of using button

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
 let vc = // Declare your viewController
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
}
```

If you want to send which cell's button clicked just add `cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAt` and modify `goDetail` with

```
 @objc func goDetail(sender : UIButton){ 
     sender.tag // while give your selected cell index
    }
```

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much! But I still have one question, the code `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)` doesn't work, but vc does have value. I make the cell tile the entire page, could this be the reason?

Comment: If you didn't embed navigationController to your ViewController this  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true) doesnt work. Can you please check it